# Express always matches the HTTP path to the last configured route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this issue where a bunch of Express routes are configured, the last one's path being `/admin`. When I request any path from the server, only the callback for the `/admin` route is invoked.

Here's my main Node.js source file to see how routes are being set up:

```js
require('babel/register')({
    stage: 0
});

var React = require('react/addons'),
    express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    path = require('path'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    pg = require('pg'),
    pgpromise = require('./server/pg-promise'),
    Page = require('./ui/js/Page'),
    pgrest = require('./server/pgrest'),
    App = React.createFactory(require('./ui/js/App'));

const CONNECTION_STRING = 'postgres://foobar:foobar@localhost/postgres';

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'ui'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

pgrest.init(
    app,
    CONNECTION_STRING
).then(function(api) {
    // React server-side rendering
    for (var pageKey in Page) {
        if (Page.hasOwnProperty(pageKey)) {
            var page = Page[pageKey];
            if (page.serverRendered) {
                app.get(page.path, function(req, res) {

                    console.log(req.path + ' matched ' + page.path);

                    function render(data) {
                        var reactHtml = React.renderToString(App({
                            initialPageName: page.name,
                            initialPageParams: req.params,
                            initialPageQuery: req.query,
                            pageData: data
                        }));

                        res.render('index', { reactHtml: reactHtml });
                    }

                    if (page.restPath) {
                        var restFunction = api.get[page.restPath];
                        if (restFunction) {
                            restFunction(req).then(render).fail(function(err) {
                                if (err.status == 401 && !err.loggedIn) {
                                    // Redirect to the login page if the REST status is 401 and the user isn't logged in.
                                    res.redirect('/login');
                                } else {
                                    // Render the requested page with the error details shown.
                                    res.render('index', {
                                        reactHtml: React.renderToString(App({
                                            initialPageName: page.name,
                                            initialPageParams: req.params,
                                            initialPageQuery: req.query,
                                            notFound: err.status == 404,
                                            notAuthorized: err.status == 401,
                                            unknownError: [401, 404].indexOf(err.status) < 0 ? (err.message || 'An unknown error occurred.') : null
                                        }))
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            render();
                        }
                    } else {
                        render();
                    }
                });
            }

            console.log(page.name + ' => ' + page.path);
        }
    }

    // 404
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        var err = new Error('Not Found');
        err.status = 404;
        next(err);
    });

    app.listen(3001);
}).fail(function(err) {
    console.error('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Here's `Page`:

```js
module.exports = {
    Home: {
        name: 'Home',
        path: '/',
        pageParams: [],
        queryParams: [],
        clientRendered: true,
        serverRendered: true,
        component: require('./pages/Home'),
        restPath: null,
        dataTarget: null
    },
    Search: {
        name: 'Search',
        path: '/search',
        pageParams: [],
        queryParams: ['q'],
        clientRendered: true,
        serverRendered: true,
        component: require('./pages/Search'),
        restPath: null,
        dataTarget: null
    },
    Register: {
        name: 'Register',
        path: '/register',
        pageParams: [],
        queryParams: [],
        clientRendered: true,
        serverRendered: true,
        component: require('./pages/Register'),
        restPath: null,
        dataTarget: null
    },
    Activate: {
        name: 'Activate',
        path: '/activate',
        pageParams: [],
        queryParams: ['email', 'code'],
        clientRendered: false,
        serverRendered: true,
        component: require('./pages/Activate'),
        restPath: null,
        dataTarget: null
    },
    ForgotPassword: {
        name: 'ForgotPassword',
        path: '/forgot-password',
        pageParams: [],
        queryParams: [],
        clientRendered: true,
        serverRendered: true,
        component: require('./pages/ForgotPassword'),
        restPath: null,
        dataTarget: null
    },
    ResetPassword: {
        name: 'ResetPassword',
        path: '/reset-password',
        pageParams: [],
        queryParams: ['email', 'code'],
        clientRendered: false,
        serverRendered: true,
        component: require('./pages/ResetPassword'),
        restPath: null,
        dataTarget: null
    },
    Login: {
        name: 'Login',
        path: '/login',
        pageParams: [],
        queryParams: [],
        clientRendered: true,
        serverRendered: true,
        component: require('./pages/Login'),
        restPath: null,
        dataTarget: null
    },
    Profile: {
        name: 'Profile',
        path: '/profile',
        pageParams: [],
        queryParams: [],
        clientRendered: true,
        serverRendered: true,
        component: require('./pages/Profile'),
        restPath: '/api/1/profile',
        dataTarget: 'profile'
    },
    Member: {
        name: 'Member',
        path: '/member/:id',
        pageParams: ['id'],
        queryParams: [],
        clientRendered: true,
        serverRendered: true,
        component: require('./pages/Member'),
        restPath: '/api/1/member/:id',
        dataTarget: 'member'
    },
    Inbox: {
        name: 'Inbox',
        path: '/inbox',
        pageParams: [],
        queryParams: [],
        clientRendered: true,
        serverRendered: true,
        component: require('./pages/Inbox'),
        restPath: null,
        dataTarget: null
    },
    Administration: {
        name: 'Administration',
        path: '/admin',
        pageParams: [],
        queryParams: [],
        clientRendered: true,
        serverRendered: true,
        component: require('./pages/Administration'),
        restPath: null,
        dataTarget: null
    }
};
```

When I start the Node app I get the following output:

```
Home => /
Search => /search
Register => /register
Activate => /activate
ForgotPassword => /forgot-password
ResetPassword => /reset-password
Login => /login
Profile => /profile
Member => /member/:id
Inbox => /inbox
Administration => /admin
```

And when I go to a page in the browser, I get this console output:

`/ matched /admin`

which is clearly incorrect.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but it doesn't look like you are ending your request once you hit the page.  The loop continues.  Try a return statement or res.send or somehting along those lines.

Comment: That `for` loop iterates only once, when the server is started, after that `pgrest` component has initialized.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, just on your code there: When you include `pg-promise`, do not include `pg` also, because `pg-promise` exposes the `pg` it uses via property `pg` after initialization, i.e. `require('pg-promise')(/*options*/).pg`.

Comment: That's actually my own little library, not [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise). Having said that, `pg` is an old `require` I didn't get around to removing yet. And `pg-promise` itself is also no longer used in the main js file. It's all wrapped inside `pgrest` (yet another one of my little libraries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace

```
for (var pageKey in Page) {
  if (Page.hasOwnProperty(pageKey)) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

with

```
Object.keys(Page).forEach(function(pageKey) {
  // ...
});
```

Otherwise your references to `page` inside your route handlers will not be what you expect, and from the looks of it, that could be what is causing your problem.

The reason `page` references the unexpected value is because `for`, `while`, `do`, etc. do not create closures for the code inside their blocks. So what happens is `page` is hoisted to the nearest closure (the `then()` callback) and its value gets re-assigned for each iteration of the loop. However, when your route handler functions actually get executed, `page` is (by that time) pointing to the last value set during the execution of the loop (in the past). The last value of `page` would be the admin route because that was the last property value in `Page`.

Using `forEach()` creates a new closure so that the value of `page` is "captured" and thus will always refer to the value that you expect inside the route handler.

Comment: That will iterate over the page keys, not the page objects. But I will try that iteration style and see what happens.

Comment: This style of iteration worked, by I'd like you to correct the answer before I accept it. It should be `Object.keys(Page).forEach(function(pageKey) { var page = Page[pageKey]; /* ... */ });`

Comment: It fixed the problem, but I still don't know why, because we're still looking up objects by key from the same `Page` object.

Comment: @SteveTaylor I've explained it a bit more in my answer. I hope that makes it a bit clearer as to what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It seems the issue is stupid JavaScript variable scoping. Variables are scoped to functions rather than blocks, so that with the `for`-`in` loop, there is only one `page` variable and by the time any request handler is invoked, it points to the last one, which is `Page.Administration`. The extra closure fixes this.

Comment: Just adding a note that this problem is solved by ES6's `let` which is block scoped.